# Using separate Bluetooth keyboard and mouse simultaneously with my iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, ipados

With the recent announcement of the Magic Keyboard for iPad I've been looking to see what I can improvise during the current COVID-19 supplies crunch. I already have a Bluetooth keyboard that I use with my iPad. My iPad is running iPadOS 13.4.

Would I be able to purchase a generic Bluetooth mouse from a retailer and use that simultaneously with the generic Bluetooth keyboard in interacting with my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be able to purchase a generic Bluetooth mouse from a retailer and use that simultaneously with the generic Bluetooth keyboard in interacting with my iPad?

Yes. It's possible to simultaneously pair a Bluetooth keyboard and a Bluetooth mouse with an iPad running iPadOS 13.4 or later. The screenshot shows an Apple Magic Keyboard and Apple Magic Mouse 2 paired and used simultaneously.

[image]

Before you invent into a generic Bluetooth keyboard and a mouse, make sure they are compatible with iPad and you'd be fine.